# How to display array numbers one by one (Irvine 32 library Visual Studio 2019 ASM)

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2019, irvine32

I need to write each manual input arrays to the screen one by one but when I try to write the first array (0) I get an output of 5 to the screen. I also need to exchange the value of the fifth array to the second array which I believe I have done correctly. 
When the program runs, it tells me to enter my numbers, so I enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, but
my output is 5? It should be 1.
Here is my code:

```
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data       ;// write your data in this section

myArray WORD 6 DUP(? )
prompt BYTE "Enter a number", 0dh, 0ah, 0
prompt1 BYTE "The number at position 0 is ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
prompt2 BYTE "The number at position 1 is ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
prompt3 BYTE "The number at position 2 is ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
prompt4 BYTE "The number at position 3 is ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
prompt5 BYTE "The number at position 4 is ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
prompt6 BYTE "The number at position 5 is ", 0dh, 0ah, 0



.code       ;// write your program here
main proc




    mov edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov myArray[0], ax

    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov myArray[1 * SIZEOF WORD], ax

    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov myArray[2 * SIZEOF WORD], ax

    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov myArray[3 * SIZEOF WORD], ax

    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov myArray[4 * SIZEOF WORD], ax

    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov myArray[5 * SIZEOF WORD], ax

    mov ax, myArray[4 * SIZEOF WORD]
    xchg myArray[1], ax
    movzx eax, myArray[1]
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf


    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
    call WriteString

    mov myArray [0 * SIZEOF WORD], ax
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
```

When I use `mov myArray [0 * SIZEOF WORD], ax` I get "The number at position 0 is 5." but it's supposed to be 1. 
When I use `mov ax, myArray[0]` instead of `mov myArray [0 * SIZEOF WORD], ax` I get "The number at position 0 is 1281." I'm confused, why are there different outputs for different ways of writing the first array to the screen? 
Please help me write the first array correctly to the screen.

Comment: `myArray[1]` is wrong, as it references the top half of a word. It's unclear what you wanted to do there.

Comment: @Jester For myArray[1] what i'm trying to do is enter a number for the second value of the array, store it, and then print it to the screen.

Comment: You read the value into `mov myArray[5 * SIZEOF WORD]` though and then you exchange `myArray[4 * SIZEOF WORD]` for whatever reason. Anyway, to get the second number you forgot to `* SIZEOF WORD`.

Comment: @Jester I exchanged `myArray[4 * SIZEOF WORD]` for whatever reason so that I can exchange the fifth array value with the second - hence the code `mov ax, myArray[4 * SIZEOF WORD]
    xchg myArray[1], ax
    movzx eax, myArray[1]
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf`

Comment: @Jester Secondly, I am not trying to get the second number here, I am trying to get the first one. I need to enter the first array value, store it, and then print it on the screen. As for the  `* SIZEOF WORD` code I forgot, I put it into the first `mov myArray[0]` and I still get the same output.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, `myArray[1]` destroys the top half of the first number (and the bottom half of the second). I still don't understand why you read into `myArray[5 * SIZEOF WORD]` if you really need to "enter a number for the second value of the array" which would be `1*`. Also why are you exchanging `4*` which is not even touched.

Answer (score 0):

The array for which you've inputted 6 values will hold these 12 bytes (6 words stored in little endian format):

```
1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0  array
^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
0   1   2   3   4   5    index
```

When tasked to exchange the fifth array element with the second array element, you correctly used array element indexes 4 and 1 because all indexing starts at zero.
Now array addressing in assembly programming doesn't use element *indexes* but rather depends on element *offsets*. This is why you multiply the index by `SIZEOF WORD`. Too bad you forgot to write this scale factor when talking to the second array element.
This is what happened:

`mov ax, myArray[4 * SIZEOF WORD]` reads the word at offset 8 and so `AX` becomes 0005h.

```
1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0  array
  ^             ^
  1             8        offset
```

`xchg myArray[1], ax` writes `AX` at offset 1 thus overwriting part of the 1st and 2nd array elements

```
1,5,0,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0  array
  ^             ^
  1             8        offset
```

`movzx eax, myArray[1]` does not retrieve the 2nd array element because even though 1 is the correct *index*, it is not the correct *offset*. This explains why you get a 5 displayed.

---

> When I use mov myArray [0 * SIZEOF WORD], ax I get "The number at position 0 is 5." but it's supposed to be 1.

Simply because you didn't actually load that first element in the `EAX` register! You've mistakenly **written** to the 1st element, followed by displaying whatever happened to be in `EAX`. And that was the value 5.

> When I use mov ax, myArray[0] instead, I get "The number at position 0 is 1281."

This time you correctly read the 1st element, but given that the `xchg` part of your program disrupted the 1st and 2nd elements, you can only get what's in there.

```
1,5,0,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0  array
^
0                        offset
```

A low byte of 1 and a high byte of 5. Together they produce 1281 (1 + 256 * 5).

---

Try this:

```
; exchange the fifth and second elements
mov     ax, myArray[4 * SIZEOF WORD]   ; read 5th element
mov     dx, myArray[1 * SIZEOF WORD]   ; read 2nd element
mov     myArray[4 * SIZEOF WORD], dx   ; write new 5th element
mov     myArray[1 * SIZEOF WORD], ax   ; write new 2nd element

; print the first element
mov     edx, OFFSET prompt1
call    WriteString
movzx   eax, myArray[0 * SIZEOF WORD]   ; read 1st element
call    WriteDec
call    Crlf
```

Please notice that here exchanging the 2 elements does indeed what it says. Your code only **copied** the 5th element over the 2nd element!